# Can't read data from firestore database (android application)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't read data from the firestore database. I can write to it although sometimes the data appears on firestore console (very) late.
And i can Delete a record although it is only delete (from firestore console) when i do a write.

It is some stupid simple error that i make, but i can't find it. Buffers? Setting? i don't know :-(

It looks like firestore is delayed responding, it never reach the line with:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful())
      ....
```

Below the logcat lines...

I am using java/android app

Thanks in advance for any help

> ```
> ,, E/PlayMissionActivity: sleep 2 <==
> ,, E/PlayMissionActivity: sleep 2 <==
> ,, W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Firestore backend.
> ,, E/PlayMissionActivity: sleep 2 <==
> ```

My Code (just a copy of the samples)

```
public class MyPlay extends AppCompatActivity { 
    FirebaseFirestore dbRef = null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        initDB();
        getDocument();

        int q=0;
        while (q<10) {
           try {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
           q += 1;
           Log.e(LOG_TAG, "sleep 2 " + "<==");
        }
    }
    public void initDB() {
        dbRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
              .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
              .build();
        dbRef.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
    }
    public void getDocument() {
        DocumentReference docRef = dbRef.collection("users").document("123");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                   if (document.exists()) {
                      Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------> DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                   } else {
                      Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------> No such document");
                   }
               } else {
                   Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------> get failed with ", task.getException());
               }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'    
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'    
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Firestore data:

```
users/123/born=1815
users/123/first="Ada"
users/123/last="Lovelace"
```

Comment: can you explain what the purpose is of that 20 seconds delay?

Comment: Have you deploy any custom function on firestore ?

Comment: 20 secs delay is just waiting for the answer

Comment: no custom functions deployed on firestore

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was indeed fundamental.
Basically i didn't understand the concept of threads, events etc.
When a thread (event) is running, the thread that is reading firestore db is waiting for finishing the main thread. (Pseudo code, when the onCreate is finished)

Probably someone can explain it better i am just an old amature

So what isn't working (pseudo code android activity):

```
onCreat{
    object = readFirestore
    print object.id   <== this line will give you an error
}
readFirestore() {
    read id
    onSucces
        object = document.toObject()
}
```

So what's working fine:

```
onCreat{
    object = readFirestore
}
readFirestore() {
    read id
    onSucces
        object = document.toObject()
        print object.id   <== this line will print your result 
}
```